# ElasticSearch 5 Sort by Keyword Field Case Insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are using ElasticSearch 5.
I have a field `city` using a custom analyzer and the following mapping.

**Analyzer**

```
       "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "lowercase_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "trim"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
}
```

Mapping

```
  "city": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
  }
```

I am doing this so that I can do a case insensitive sort on the city field. Here is an example query that I am trying to run

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "email": {
        "value": "some_email@test.com"
      }
    }
  },
"sort": [
    {
      "city": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true
>   on [city] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the
>   inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."

I don't want to turn on `FieldData` and incur a performance hit in ElasticSearch. I would like to have a `Keyword` field that is not case sensitive, so that I can perform more meaningful aggregations and sorts on it. Is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this, using [`multi_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/multi-fields.html).

In Elasticsearch 5.0 onwards, [**`string`** field types were split out](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) into two separate types, [**`text`**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/text.html) field types that are analyzed and can be used for search, and [**`keyword`**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/keyword.html) field types that are not analyzed and are suited to use for sorting, aggregations and exact value matches.

With dynamic mapping in Elasticsearch 5.0 (i.e. let Elasticsearch infer the type that a document property should be mapped to), a json `string` property is mapped to a `text` field type, with a sub-field of "keyword" that is mapped as a `keyword` field type and the setting `ignore_above:256`.

With NEST 5.x automapping, a `string` property on your POCO will be automapped in the same way as dynamic mapping in Elasticsearch maps it as per above e.g. given the following document

```
public class Document
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

[automapping it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/auto-map.html)

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

produces

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "property": {
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can now use `property` for sorting using `Field(f => f.Property.Suffix("keyword")`. Take a look at [Field Inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/field-inference.html#_complex_field_name_expressions) for more examples.

`keyword` field types have [**`doc_values`**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/doc-values.html) enabled by default, which means that a columnar data structure is built at index time and this is what provides efficient sorting and aggregations.

To add a custom analyzer at index creation time, we can automap as before, but then provide overrides for fields that we want to control the mapping for with `.Properties()`

```
client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(aa => aa
                .Custom("lowercase_analyzer", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("keyword")
                    .Filters(
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "trim"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.Property)
                    .Analyzer("lowercase_analyzer")
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Keyword(k => k
                            .Name("keyword")
                            .IgnoreAbove(256)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which produces

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "trim"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "property": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```